# Conditional expectation of $\mathbf1[X_1=0]\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d Poisson RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d Poisson random variables with mean $\mu$. Let $S=X_1+X_2+ \dots + X_n$. Set $Y=\mathbf{1}[X_1=0]$. Show that $$\mathbb{E}(Y\mid S)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^S$$

$$\mathbb{E}(Y\mid S) = \sum y \frac{P(Y,S)}{P(S)}$$

$S$ is of course Poisson with mean $\mu n$. I am stuck here.

Comment: Yes. It is correct. So, Y=1. And P(Y,S) = P(X_1=0,   X_2+X_3 .._X_n =S) = P(X_1 = 0) P(X_2+...X_n= s).. We can do that because they are independent. That's how far I got now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Y$ is just an indicator variable,

\begin{align}
E(Y\mid S=s)&=P(X_1=0\mid S=s)
\\&=\frac{P(X_1=0,S=s)}{P(S=s)}
\\&=\frac{P\left(X_1=0,\sum_{i=2}^nX_i=s\right)}{P(S=s)}
\\&=\frac{P(X_1=0)P\left(\sum_{i=2}^nX_i=s\right)}{P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=s\right)}
\end{align}

You know that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim\mathcal P(n\mu)$ due to independence of $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$.

It follows on simplification that $$E(Y\mid S=s)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^s$$

If we are estimating the unknown parameter $μ$, then this conditional expectation indeed gives us the UMVUE of $P(X_1=0)=e^{−\mu}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the expression $ \mathbb{E}(Y ~|~ S) $ can be significantly simplified. Since, $Y$ takes only two values ($0$ and $1$) then we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y ~|~ S) = \mathbb{P}(Y = 1 ~|~ S) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 ~|~ S) \equiv \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 ~|~ X_1 + \dots + X_n = S)
$$
For the latter we use Bayes theorem along with the properties of Poisson distribution. 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 ~|~ X_1 + \dots + X_n = S) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 \cap X_2 + \dots + X_n = S)} {\mathbb{P}( X_1 + \dots + X_n = S)} = \frac{e^{-\mu} \cdot (\mu(n -1))^S e^{-\mu(n-1)}}{(\mu n)^S e^{-\mu n}} = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^S,
$$
as required.

Comment: The formula $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 ~|~ X_1 + \dots + X_n = S)$$ is faulty here. Note that, by definition, $$X_1 + \dots + X_n = S$$ hence, actually, $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 ~|~ X_1 + \dots + X_n = S)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0 )=e^{-\mu}$$